# Find duplicate rows - keep one entry

Tags: sql-server

I have a `sql-server` table like this:

```
date : date
symbol : string
open : money
...
```

In the act of collecting historical data, I may have accidentally added the same data for a given date more than once. I need to keep one of the rows. But any more than one entry for the given symbol on a given date needs to be deleted. For example, this is wrong (two entries for INTC on 2/2/2019):

```
1/31/2019 INTC 48.32
2/2/2019 INTC 49.51
2/2/2019 INTC 49.51
```

How do I delete, per each symbol, duplicate rows automatically through a `sql script` and leave the rest of the data that does not contain duplicates alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some CTE "magic":

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [date], [Symbol], [open],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE [date] = '20190202'
      AND [Symbol] = 'INTC'
      AND [open] = 49.51)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```

If you want to `DELETE` any duplicates you've created and assuming that a duplicate denotes 2 or more rows that share the same values for `date`, `symbol` and `open`, then you can do:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [date], [Symbol], [open],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [date], [Symbol], [open] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM YourTable)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```

If you should only have one entry per day (or day and symbol perhaps), then create it as a UNIQUE constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT UK_date_symbol UNIQUE ([date],symbol);
```